# regex to find more than one occurence of comment within a block

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have some markdown files in which I follow a certain Q & A format to sync my flashcards from my note-taking software Obsidian to Anki. Somehow, there seems to be messup where there were duplicate questions created in Anki due to newline characters. I want to find these duplicates and delete them out from my note and remove the redundant newline characters which caused these duplicates questions to happen. Here is a sample data file:

```
### Alias

Q: what check to do before creating an alias?

A: check whether any other command exists by that name using `type new-alias-name`
<!--ID: 1643091253375-->

---

Q: syntax to create an alias?

A: `alias name='string'`
<!--ID: 1645446702965-->

- no spaces before or after the equal sign
- single quotes around the command sequence
![[Pasted image 20220125092954.png]]
<!--ID: 1643091253408-->

---

### Redirection/Piping

Q: output of `> ls-output.txt`

A: the file will be truncated if it exists or it would be created.
<!--ID: 1645087988730-->

- Simply using the redirection operator with no command preceding it will truncate an existing file or create a new empty file
<!--ID: 1643351731943-->

---
```

Each comment which has a format like `<!--ID: 1645446702965-->` is a flashcard in Anki. In the 2nd question to create an alias, you can see that there are 2 IDs. I want to delete the first one and remove the newlines after that so that there is only one ID comment that remains.

Here is the regex I am trying -
`^A:.+?(<!--ID:\s\d+-->)(?!---).+(<!--ID:\s\d+-->)`

Here I am trying to match the Answer sections where the ID comments occur twice. I am using a negative lookahead to allow anything other than `---`. But the highlight shows that the regex is reaching too far. I am quite new to Regex and just finished one round of reading 'Mastering Regular expressions by Jeffrey Friedl'. I am still trying to wrap my head around greedy and lazy behaviour. Any guidance to help me move forward on this would be appreciated.

[image: regex snapshot in regex101.com]

I have my regex with the data posted here in case anyone want to try:
https://regex101.com/r/jBSc8Y/1

Comment: So is it for JavaScript or Python? Why is PCRE2 selected in the regex demo? Is it for PHP? Regex flavors are not the same.

Comment: In case one can rely always on the 2 newlines and the block/section termination of `---` a straightforward solution was ... [`<!--.*?-->\n{2}(?!---)`](https://regex101.com/r/jBSc8Y/2)

Comment: This more generic one (in terms of identifying/targeting the correct duplicate) ... [`<!--\s*ID\:\s*\d+\s*-->(?=\n*-\s+)`](https://regex101.com/r/jBSc8Y/4) ... to my surprise works as well and also is more reliable. My surprise comes from the working `*` quantifier within the positive lookahead. I always thought they are not allowed with PCRE/2. But maybe Wiktor could shed some light on it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Either regex in JS or Python would do. I did not pay too much attention to the flavour selected in the regex tester as the regex I am testing is fairly uncomplicated and should work on most flavours (given what I learnt from Jeffrey Friedl's book). I am sorry if this made it inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the versions already linked with the comments, the most practical solution might be to use a string replacement with a simple regex like [`/<!--\s*ID:\s*\d+\s*-->\n+-\s+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/jBSc8Y/6) ... where one would match ...

- `<!--\s*ID:\s*\d+\s*-->` ... the exact `ID` format
- `\n+-\s+` ... followed by at least one new line, a hyphen, and a whitespace(-sequence).

The last bullet-point also describes what makes an `ID` format a duplicate.

Then one just needs to replace the match by `-` .

```js
const sampleText = `

### Alias

Q: what check to do before creating an alias?

A: check whether any other command exists by that name using \`type new-alias-name\`
<!--ID: 1643091253375-->

---

Q: syntax to create an alias?

A: \`alias name='string'\`
<!--ID: 1645446702965-->

- no spaces before or after the equal sign
- single quotes around the command sequence
![[Pasted image 20220125092954.png]]
<!--ID: 1643091253408-->

---

### Redirection/Piping

Q: output of \`> ls-output.txt\`

A: the file will be truncated if it exists or it would be created.
<!--ID: 1645087988730-->

- Simply using the redirection operator with no command preceding it will truncate an existing file or create a new empty file
<!--ID: 1643351731943-->

`;

const regXDuplicateId = /<!--\s*ID:\s*\d+\s*-->\n+-\s+/g;

console.log(
  sampleText.replace(regXDuplicateId, '- ')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you so much for the immediate response. Sorry, I could not get back to you immediately. You have redefined the problem in a way to make it easy to apply regex - Taking inspiration from your solution, I have broken down my problem into a few different regex expressions and trying them out.